# JavaFX Maven project error when adding sqljdbc dependency to pom.xml (netbeans 8.2 jdk8)

Tags: hibernate, maven, javafx, netbeans, pom.xml

I am new to Maven JavaFX projects. I am trying to create a connection with SQL Server using Hibernate (5.4) still in fase one adding dependencies all is fine until I add the sqljdbc4 dependency to my **pom.xml**.

The project builds fine but it does not run, and shows this error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project mavenproject1: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
```

My **pom.xml** looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.triz</groupId>
<artifactId>mavenproject1</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>mavenproject1</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <mainClass>com.triz.mavenproject1.MainApp</mainClass>
</properties>
<repositories>

    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Central Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

</repositories>
<organization>
    <!-- Used as the 'Vendor' for JNLP generation -->
    <name>Your Organisation</name>
</organization>
<dependencies>
      <!-- hibernate -->
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.15.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.15.Final</version>
        <!-- will come with Hibernate core-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
        <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
             <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
      <!--sqlJDBC-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
  

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludeScope>system</excludeScope>
                        <excludeGroupIds>junit,org.mockito,org.hamcrest</excludeGroupIds>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                    
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>${java.home}/../bin/javafxpackager</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>-createjar</argument>
                            <argument>-nocss2bin</argument>
                            <argument>-appclass</argument>
                            <argument>${mainClass}</argument>
                            <argument>-srcdir</argument>
                            <argument>${project.build.directory}/classes</argument>
                            <argument>-outdir</argument>
                            <argument>${project.build.directory}</argument>
                            <argument>-outfile</argument>
                            <argument>${project.build.finalName}.jar</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>                            
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>${java.home}/bin/java</executable>
                        <commandlineArgs>${runfx.args}</commandlineArgs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>  
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <bootclasspath>${sun.boot.class.path}${path.separator}${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</bootclasspath>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalClasspathElements>
                    <additionalClasspathElement>${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</additionalClasspathElement>
                </additionalClasspathElements>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Your javafxpackager command failed.  Try using `-X` to learn more

Comment: the debugger console didn't indecate / show anything ! build was successful

Comment: If it was successful then everything’s fine?!  If not investigate as said.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen The error message indicates that it's not `javafxpacakger` it the configuration afterwards with id `default-cli`. @Hadjer Mohamedi was this part added automatically by NetBeans? I don't see `runfx.args`. Can you paste the entire build output?

Comment: @asbachb you are right.  It is the next exec configuration. Perhaps `..` is missing?

Comment: thank you to everyone who tried to help me i actualy don't know what was the probem or what was i doing wrong but i replaced the sqljdbc drive with jtds drive and my probleme ws solved and i was able to run and connect to my sqlvserver data base using hibernate with no problem thank you everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you to everyone who tried to help me i actualy don't know what was the probem or what was i doing wrong but i replaced the sqljdbc drive with jtds drive and my probleme ws solved and i was able to run and connect to my sqlvserver data base using hibernate with no problem thank you everyone.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
  <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```